# PHP detect who opened the page

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I googled this question and I couldn't find an answer.

I have a page generated by PHP that generates a JSON string that I use javascript/jQuery/AJAX to retrieve it.

I would like to have a message appear if a user opens this backend page directly by PHP but if retrieved by AJAX it still work as normal.

Is this possible in PHP and what would I be looking at to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just check the headers to see how it was requested:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'))
{
    /* Do something with the AJAX request */
}
else
{
    /* Do something else */
}
```

Just check to make sure your server supports `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH`. Not all do, though off the top of my head I know Apache 2 does.

Comment: @d11wtq: Yes, but not all servers.

Comment: Is this a jQuery thing, or a standard implemented by all browsers?  Excuse my ignorance, I'd never seen this before and see that jQuery's source adds this header.  PS: Downvote wasn't from me, I agree that this would be a viable answer if it's a standard header ;)

Comment: @d11wtq: This is added by all modern browsers for AJAX requests, to the best of my knowledge. I don't use anything for AJAX except jQuery so my knowledge may be partial.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) to keep track of where the request is coming from.

Browsers themselves aren't required to (and don't, AFAIK) identify AJAX request any differently to other requests.

Comment: Sure you *could* use a nonce, or you could check the headers. AJAX requests are different then other HTTP requests.